# Conditional Expectations, Sigma Algebras and Indicator Functions.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

We have $Z_t$ a random variable, and $S_t$ is a sigma algebra. The subscript is essentially time. I want to understand the relationship given below, given another random variable $V$, and a constant $A$. All random variables are on the same probability space.

$E[(A - V) \mathbb{1}_{\{Z_t > A\}}| S_t] = E[A - V | Z_t > A, S_t] P(Z_t > A | S_t)$

Here is my reasoning. For any $\mathcal{H} \subset S_t$ we have,
$\int_\mathcal{H} (A-V) \mathbb{1}_{\{Z_t > A\}} | H] dP = \int_\mathcal{H} (A - V) \mathbb{1}_{\{Z_t > A\}}  dP$

$=\int(A-V) \mathbb{1}_{\{Z_t > A, \mathcal{H}\}} dP$

I am not sure where to go from here. The result above is really used in the paper by Glosten and Milgrom 1985. "BID, ASK Transaction Prices in a specialist market with heterogeneous informed traders"

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a probability space and $X$ a random variable. Then fix some event $H \in \mathcal{A}$, we have that
$$\nu(A)=\frac{\mu(A\cap H)}{\mu(H)} \ \ \ A \in \mathcal{A}$$
Is a probability measure. Indeed:
$$\nu(\emptyset)=\frac{\mu(\emptyset\cap H)}{\mu(H)}=0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \nu(\Omega)=\frac{\mu(\Omega\cap H)}{\mu(H)}=1$$
and for pairwise disjoint $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathcal{A}$ we also have
$$\nu(\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n)=\frac{\mu(\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n\cap H)}{\mu(H)}=\frac{\mu(\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(A_n\cap H))}{\mu(H)}=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{\mu(A_n\cap H)}{\mu(H)}=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\nu(A_n)$$
This is the conditional probability on the event $H$. The conditional expectation is
$$E[X|H]:=\int_\Omega X(\omega) \nu(d\omega)=\int_\Omega X(\omega) \frac{\mu(d\omega\cap H)}{\mu(H)}$$
Thus
$$E[X|H]\mu(H)=\int_\Omega X(\omega) \mu(d\omega\cap H)=\int_HX(\omega) \mu(d\omega)=E[X\mathbb{I}_H]$$

Comment: The set $H:=\{Z_t > A\}$ is an event, while $S_t$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (and everything is conditioned on it)

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks.

Comment: I see what you are doing. So $E[X|Z_t > A, S_t] P(Z_t > A | S_t] = E[X \mathbb{1}_{\{Z_t > A\}} | S_t]$ is what you have shown. Your H is actually the event. I did not realize that. Thank You, I should have read your answer a bit more carefully.